xlrd library even after installed is not recognized in Spyder
I installed the xlrd library, but still when I run my python script in Spyder it is not recognized.
See the attached images below.
I have already updated Anaconda Pyhon.
Could you help me resolve this situation, please?

I have already updated Anaconda Pyhon.
